# Multiprocessing Process, Queue and Objects

Tags: python, object, process, multiprocessing, queue

I am new to Python `multiprocessing` and simply can't get my head around how this piece of code is working:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue


class C:
    dic = {}


def put_in_queue(q, v):
    c = C()
    print("before update:", c.dic)
    c.dic.update({0: v})
    print("after update", c.dic)
    q.put(c)


def main():
    queue = Queue()
    put_in_queue(queue, 0)
    c = queue.get()
    print("get from queue dic:", c.dic)

    p = Process(target=put_in_queue, args=(queue, 1))
    p.start()
    p.join()
    c = queue.get()
    print("get from queue modified by process dic:", c.dic)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Its output is the following:

```
before update: {}
after update {0: 0}
get from queue dic: {0: 0}
before update: {0: 0}
after update {0: 1}
get from queue modified by process dic: {0: 0}
```

There are basically two main questions that i can't seem to answer:

1. Why does the update to the dictionary made by the process do not propagate back to the main process even though the modified object should be passed through the queue.
2. Why does the in the process newly created object seem to already have the changed value for the dict even though it is newly created and the update on it hasn't been made yet?

My guess would be that it has something to do with passing an custom object instead of some simple type.

Maybe this is a pretty stupid question but i just don't understand it yet. Some explanation or help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your sub-questions stem from a misunderstanding of how classes work in Python. The way you defined class `C`:

```
class C:
    dic = {}
```

means that *all* class instances will share the same `dic` attribute because it's a *`class`*, not instance, attribute when declared like that.

To change it into an *instance* attribute, you would need to do something like this:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dic = {}
```

This gives each instance its own independent attribute (that won't be affected by changes made to it through other instances, which is what happens when it's done the other way).

With that change, the output from your script becomes:

```
before update: {}
after update {0: 0}
get from queue dic: {0: 0}
before update: {}
after update {0: 1}
get from queue modified by process dic: {0: 1}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can't believe i fell for such a simple mistake! Thanks again :)